# What is the form factor of the Fujitsu D3219-Axx mainboard (in the Fujitsu TX1310 M1 server)

Tags: motherboard, form-factor

Despite thorough research, I could not find out the form factor of the Fujitsu TX1310 M1 server's mainboard, which is a D3219-Axx.

I have found the manuals here: http://manuals.ts.fujitsu.com/index.php?id=5406-5635-5814-16661-18262

Unfortunately, none of the manuals tells the mainboard's form factor. Does anybody know if I can mount that board into a standard mATX, ATX or eATX case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my opinion, it is an ATX form factor motherboard.

I looked through a number of spec sheets, websites, and even some videos.  However, I could not find anything definitively stating what form factor it was.  That being said, it definitely *appears* to be an ATX form factor motherboard in what *appears* to be an ATX form factor case.  It probably is, but there is no guarantee.

> One important thing to note:

This machine does ***NOT*** use a standard ATX power supply.  It is a non-standard/custom power supply.  It might not mount properly in the case you were planning to put it in.  Additionally, even if it does mount, the cables running to the motherboard are very short and do not use the standard ATX connector, so extenders will not work.  It also apparently uses non standard voltages (11v) on some if the pins.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen some of these in real life a couple of months ago.

The motherbaord is a non-standard ATX form-factor. It has the ATX size, but it is just different enough that it won't easily fit in a standard case.

Some of the mounting holes are in the wrong spot. You can only mount it with 2 or 3 screws depending on the layout of a normal case.
The backplane insert for the connectors is fixed to the original case, so you can't take that out to put in another case.
I could be wrong but it looks as if the backplane connectors are also somewhat offset from a normal ATX baord which may mean they could potentially interfere with the case.
The power-supply is totally non-standard. Not easily replaceable by a standard PU.
The various front-panel headers for case-lights, on/off switch, HD led, audio, etc. are non-standard.